# $p$-adic-valuation of an expression involving Bernoulli numbers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

Let $p = 43, 67$ or $163$ (three primes such that $h(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})) = 1$) and consider $k = (p+1)/2$.  I'm interested in computing the $p$-adic valuation of the expression 
\begin{equation}
1+\frac{l}{B_l},
\end{equation}
where $l = k + m(p-1),~m\geq 0$. Note that, by the Kummer congruences and the fact that $h(-p) \equiv -2B_k~(\mathrm{mod}~p)$, we have
\begin{equation}
v_p(1+l/B_l)\geq 1.
\end{equation} 
In fact, I have observed by numerical computations that this inequality is an equality for many value of $m$. I have also observed that if $m$ is such that $2m+1 = dp$ for an integer $d$, then the valuation of $1+l/B_l$ seems to be equal to $2$.

These observations seem very mysterious for me, so I was wondering if anybody had an idea to explain this? Thanks !